# Restringir uso de una app node js en solo algunos dispositivos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

He escrito una pequeña node js con express, pero quiero limitar su uso a ciertos dispositivos; lo he intentado por la mac del dispositivo pero no he podido obtener la, que otra forma me sugieren?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo la lectura de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), de esa manera te puedes informar acerca de la manera adecuada de formular una pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Por la forma que está redactada tu pregunta parece basarse en opiniones. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y agregues lo que has intentado, además indica exactamente y con mayor claridad el objetivo deseado y el problema encontrado. Debes aportar el código relevante para poder reproducir el problema, puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos